# Java multi-threaded server-client communication

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serialization, synchronization

I'm having a frustrating issue with one problem I'm trying to do in order to prep for an university exam - there should be a bunch of clients accessing a resource through a tcp socket on a separate server, which synchronizes the access. I've got a basic entrypoint class with main essentially instantiating either the clients or the server and a class for the object being serialized and passed through the socket:

DataPacket.class source here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class DataPacket implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final public String payload;
    final public String creator;
    final public Date timestamp;

    public DataPacket(String creator, String payload){
        this.creator = creator;
        this.payload = payload;
        this.timestamp = new Date();
    }

}
```

client.class source here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class client extends Thread implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    public client(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 12345);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            Random rand = new Random();

// obviously the only reason to have this loop here is to initiate a bunch of access 
// requests to the server, but for debugging purposes I've removed the extra cycles
// and stuck to only one;

            for(int i=0; i<1; i++){ 
                DataPacket data = new DataPacket(this.name, Integer.toString(rand.nextInt()));
                out.writeObject(data);
                out.flush();
            }
            sock.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and finally the server.class source is here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class server extends Thread{
    private int port;
    private DataPacket dp;
    public boolean running=false;

    public void updateData(DataPacket dp){
        this.dp=dp;
    }

    public server(int port){
        this.port = port;
        }

    public void run(){
        this.running = true;
        while (running){
            openSocket();
            }
        }

    public void openSocket(){
        try {
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(this.port, 50, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            while (true){
                Socket incomming = s.accept();
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(incomming.getInputStream());
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(incomming.getOutputStream());
                synchronized (dp){
                    while ((dp = (DataPacket) in.readObject()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(dp.creator + "passed a frame @" + dp.timestamp + " :"+dp.payload);
                    } while (in.readObject() == null){
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        System.out.print(".");
                    }
                }
                s.close();
            }           
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm not sure why, but apparently the client requires a input stream defined too (not doing any talk-back from the server to the client, but it blows up with a bunch of refused connection exceptions unless I do declare one. I went on the safe side and declared one output on the server just in case. Unfortunately though it seems that either the client doesn't pass the object through the socket, resp the server doesn't get it, or that I fail somehwere miserably with the serialization and deserialization..

While I'm at it, I'd appreciate a few advises about the synchronization of the data access on the server - will this "synchronised (dp)" do the job, or do I need to put the threads of the clients manually into a wait queue and get one of them manually out with notify() to transmit their serialized data?

Thanks in advance!
vlex

Comment: I'm surprised you're not seeing a `NullPointerException on` your server side - you're synchronizing on `null`. Anyway, please elaborate on what actually happens. How do you know the client doesn't send or the server doesn't get the message? Have you ran either through a debugger? What behavior does it exhibit. You were getting connection errors - what was the stack trace?

Comment: I used to get nullpointer exceptions, but can't recall how I fixed them (have spent the last few days struggling with this and the sleep deprivation doesn't help much remembering what was all I did...) Haven't tried debugging it yet, because I'm not sure my approach is correct to begin with. As soon as I have a moment to tinker with it will definitely try seeing what's being passed through the socket if anything at all :) The connection errors were either because the socket was in use, or because the connection was refused. Fixed it by lwoering the number of active connections at a time to 1

Comment: and by declaring an unused input stream for the client socket.

Comment: Just tried running 10 clients at the same time and my stack was filled with:
`java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at server.openSocket(server.java:26)
 at server.run(server.java:20)`

Comment: can't get the formatting to work - sorry...

Comment: Your server should start once... are you sure that you do not run 10 times the server while running the client?? What is your main class looks like which is triggering the client and server?

Comment: they're two separate entry points with separate loops invoking the instantization of the server and clients, so I'm pretty sure I'm not starting 10 servers. Will update the OP with the source of the two mains if you think they would be relevant...

Comment: i.e. these are two separate projects without any common resources whatsoever (despite the copied datapackage class, which is used only for objects to be serialized and passed through the socket

Comment: **Never** derive from `Thread` if you want to implement a task that should be run by a thread. Instead, implement `Runnable` and hand it over to a `Thread` - or even better, an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: What's the difference whether I implement runnable or extend thread? doesn't thread implement runnable thus making it pretty much the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I spent a few extra days working on it and rewrote it a couple of times and now works. Here's my example of a multithreading-enabled server:

serverentry.class:

```
package server2;

public class serverentry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        server[] serv = new server[10];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            serv[i] = new server(12345+i);
            serv[i].start();
        }
    }
}
```

server.class:

```
package server2;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class server extends Thread implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int port;
    private static String data = "nothing yet";
    public server(int port){
        this.port = port;
        System.out.println("Server thread["+(this.port-12345)+"] started");
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(this.port, 50, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            Socket accepted = sock.accept();                
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(accepted.getInputStream()));
            while(br.readLine() !=null){
                synchronized(data){
                    updateData(br.readLine());
                }
                if (br.readLine() == null) break;
            }
            sock.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    private void updateData(String streamObj){
        String[] streamArr = streamObj.split("&");
        data = streamArr[1];
        System.out.println("Data updated to "+data+" by "+streamArr[0]+" @ "+ new Date());
    }
}
```

cliententry.class:

```
package client2;

public class cliententry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        client2[] cli = new client2[10];
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            cli[i] = new client2(i);
            cli[i].start();
        }
    }
}
```

client2.class:

```
package client2;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class client2 extends Thread implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String payload;
    private int number; 
    private Random rand;
    public client2(int num){
        rand = new Random();
        this.number = num;
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            Socket sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),(12345+this.number));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
            for (int i=0; i<30; i++){
                String random = Integer.toString(this.rand.nextInt());
                this.payload = "thread[" + this.number + "]&"+random; 
                pw.write(this.payload);
                pw.write("\n");
                pw.flush();
                }
            sock.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also one of the previous times I rewrote it I used the run() menthod instead of start() which later explained why I got only 3 out of 10 updates or so - the run starts the logic in the same thread, whilst start instantiates another thread. Now it all works as a swiss clock :)

cheers,
vlex